# ¿Consume ancho de banda realizar consultas a la base de datos desde otro sitio web?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

¿Consume ancho de banda en el sitio web original el obtener datos desde otro sitio?

Estoy obteniendo con Ajax datos del 'sitio web original' desde otro sitio web, hago simplemente eso, me interesa saber si esto gasta recursos del servidor de ese sitio o no, ya que quiero contratar un hosting solo para base de datos pero de pronto se consuma el ancho de banda y no pueda obtener nada después.

Este es el script que estoy utilizando desde el sitio web que obtiene los datos del sitio web donante.

```
$.ajax({
data:parameters,
url: 'get.php',
type: 'POST',
success: function(mensaje) {
    alert(mensaje);
}});
```

Comment: Considera que los proveedores de hosting pueden medir tanto tráfico entrante como saliente; en tu caso, se consume principalmente ancho de banda saliente del "sitio web original" y entrante donde haces Ajax.

Comment: Aunque evidentemente estás produciendo tráfico de datos y por tanto consumo de ancho de banda, va a depender de qué cuente la empresa de hosting como tráfico. Hay incluso algunos (fiables, de buena reputación) que no ponen restricciones al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu mismo te estas autocontestando en el momento que mencionas "Estoy ***obteniendo*** con Ajax ***datos*** del 'sitio web original'"

Cuando realizas un request mediante AJAX, en cierta manera es como si visitases esa web, así que en mayor o menor medida vas a utilizar ancho de banda y recursos del servidor al que estás haciendo el request.